# UILabel value changes after a long time

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uilabel

I have a `UIView` and in it I have a `UILabel` , when i press a button i receive data from server and I want to change the text in the label according to the new data, i have managed to do that but it takes a long time (about a minute) to change the text.
does anybody have an idea why? because I use `NSLog` to show `lbl.text` after changing and it show the new data but on screen it take time to change..

```
    NSLog(@"Sending Data to Server");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSLog(@"post: %@",post);
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (unsigned long)[postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    NSString *urlstring = [NSString stringWithFormat:JSON_URL];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlstring]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()
    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    if (!error) {
        _jsonResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:kNilOptions error:&error];


        Label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"you have: %@",[_jsonResults objectForKey:@"num"]];
```

I Have edit my answer , now it work fine, i updated my label on a background thread only, so i added

```
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()
```

and now it works great!

Comment: Might just be that your response takes a long time to be fetched. Try logging something just before you set the text.
If it's not a delay issue, it might be a thread issue. You should read about `NSThread`s and Grand Central Dispatch. It might just be on a background thread.

Comment: You're sending a http request on main thread, it's not good. Network job takes time and may block your main thread. Do it in a asynchronous way.

Comment: you are right! i added this : " dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()" and now it works fine! thank you

Comment: hey @user1994641 check my answer. use indicater for display process

Answer (score 0):

i was doing it in the back end an thats why it took so much time to change,
i add this 
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()

and now it works fine!